# Auto grow/shrink of divs to the mobile screen height

Tags: css, flexbox, height, scrollbar, viewport

I'm wondering if it's possible to get rid of vertical scroll having 3 rows viewing on a mobile device that should fit/stretch to the height of screen's and shrink when the screen height is smaller than it should be, so if there's a taller device all elements would grow proportionally to fit the whole screen's height instead of having the scrollbar that appears every time when the sum of height of the container's elements is bigger than the screen's height. What properties should I use? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with CSS Flexbox. I am posting an example that I believe creates the effect you want.

In the HTML there are three rows (header, main, footer) wrapped inside a div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <header>
                <p>Header</p>
            </header>
            <main>
                <p>Main</p>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <p>Footer</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 100vh;
}

header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex: 1 1;
}

main {
    background-color: lightcyan;
    flex: 1 1;
}

footer {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    flex: 1 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS grids and set a template with 3 rows and set the height of each row-elements to 33.33333%. This makes sure that the elements take the whole screen.

Comment: And if my mobile device's height is not enough to see all three rows at once, will it place scrollbar instead of shrinking the divs to fit them to my mobile screen's height? Thanks.

Comment: no, it will squeeze it. in that case add a media query at 600px or 900px to remove the height property.